# Проблема с миграцией баз данных в Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
при миграции базы постоянно выдает вот такую ошибку, не понимаю что нужно исправить.

Comment: Все ли данные Вы привели, как много лишних телодвижений придется сделать человеку, который захочет разобраться в Вашей проблеме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В провайдере `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` в методе `boot()` нужно добавить следующую строку:

```
function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Эта ошибка появляется из-за того, что сервер MyqSQL ниже версии 5.7.7, так как с версии ларавела 5.4 была изменена кодировка символов с `utf8` на `utf8mb4`

Comment: огромное спасибо!